# Is this google app engine / android tutorial deprecated?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, deprecated

Is [this google app engine / android tutorial](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android) deprecated?

I've been working through it and just realised `C2DM` has been replaced by `GCM`.  Is the tutorial still relevant and useful (it's been updated recently)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That looks pretty old.  The functionality appears to be replaced by Google Cloud Endpoints.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/overview

Note that Endpoints is still experimental.

Comment: I see, wow, Google Cloud Endpoints looks pretty neat.  I don't understand why it says it's been updated this month if it's so outdated.

Comment: I dunno how you got to that particular page.   The rest of the site looks up to date (try clicking on the other items in the left bar) https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started